# Querying many-to-many relation and some more data with Laravel (Lumen/Eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I have three tables.

Table 1: `posts` // Storing the twitter posts of a user
Table 2: `tags` // Storing the tags used in twitter posts
Table 3: `post_tag` // pivot-table

Now, what I want is to enter a `tag`, e.g. 'yolo' and get all posts that have this hashtag. This is fairly easy, and I have done it like this

Class Post:

```
/**
* Get the tags associated with the post
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
*/
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag')->get(['tag']);
}
```

Class Tag:

```
/**
 * Get the posts associated with the given tag
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Post');
}
```

Accessing the data:

```
/** @var Tag $tag */
try {
    $tag    = Tag::where('tag', urldecode($passedTag))->firstOrFail();
    return response()->json(['posts' => $tag->posts->toArray()]);
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    return response()->json(['errors' => 'No query results for: '. $passedTag]);
}
```

However, what I want additionaly to do, is to also get all the other tags that have been used for the post. E.g. a post has the tags `yolo` and `swag`. Now when a user enters `yolo` I want the application to show all posts being tagged with `yolo`, but also show all the other tags a post has, in this example `swag`. I've done like this

```
/** @var Tag $tag */
try {
    $tag    = Tag::where('tag', urldecode($passedTag))->firstOrFail();
    $posts  = $tag->posts;
    $fData  = [];
    foreach ($posts as $index=>$post) {
        /** @var Post $post */
        $fData[$index] = $post->toArray();
        $fData[$index]['tags'] = $post->tags();
    }
    return response()->json(['posts' => $fData]);
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    return response()->json(['errors' => 'No query results for: '. $passedTag]);
}
```

but since I'm new to Laravel (Lumen) I'm pretty sure that there is a faster way of doing it. Any advice how I would do this more performant? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) all needed relations. They will be displayed in the `toArray` aswell.

```
/** @var Tag $tag */
try {
    return response()->json([
        'posts' => Tag::with('posts')->with([
            'posts.tags' => function ($query) {
                $query->addSelect(['tag']);
             }
        ])
        ->where('tag', urldecode($passedTag))
        ->firstOrFail()->posts->toArray()
    ]);
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    return response()->json(['errors' => 'No query results for: '. $passedTag]);
}
```

Eager loading means, that you can preload any of the object's relations, at the time the object is retrieved itself. This will not only reduce the query load, but will also give you all of the data you need without additional loops or database calls. As you can see you can nest eager loading, to load relations of relations - `posts.tags`

**EDIT**

This eager loading of relation will fetch you only the tag column from the related tags:

```
'posts.tags' => function ($query) {
    $query->addSelect(['tag']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you can chain it like this. However, when using `firstOrFail()` I'm getting the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints()`

Comment: @Musterknabe Hm I am testing this in Laravel 5 atm and it is working perfectly, but maybe in Lumen there is a problem. Give me a minute to install Lumen and test this.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Yeah, maybe this has sth to do with LUmen

Comment: Just to make it more clear. I only got this problem when having the code like this: `Tag::with('posts', 'posts.tags')` but not when I got it like this: `Tag::with('posts')`

Comment: It works like you suggested when I have the tags() method like this: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag');` but not like this `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag')->get(['tag']);`, however I only want to get the tag. not everything

Comment: Yes this is wrong `$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag')->get(['tag'])`, it should be `$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag')` Because your post has many tags. This is not right way of defining relations as you did. Currently what you did return a collection as result, but it should return relation.

Comment: Hey, I have posted an answer with my two code snippets

Comment: Yes, it is wrong, however I only want to display the tag field of the Tag class, not all the other fields. I know, that I could add the `hidden` stuff, however I only want to hide it for this relation and not in general

Comment: Okay, fixed! Using `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag')->select(['tag']);` instead of get works! :) Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Musterknabe I have modified my answer to get only the `tag` column from tags, as you need. Please let me know if the change works for you :)

Comment: Thanks. Your approach is even better, because it only limits it to the specific method and not globally for the relation! Awesome, thx :)